# IOS how to POST GET DELETE PUT Rest Api

Tags: ios, api, rest

I am building my App conected to a Rest API and until now I only made a GET request with the following code :

```
//Start login process
NSString *emailstring = email.text;
NSString *passstring = pass.text;

// Create the URL from a string.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myserver.com/Rest/API/users?format=json&email=%@&password=%@",emailstring,passstring]];
NSLog(@"%@",url);

// Create a request object using the URL.
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

// Prepare for the response back from the server    
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;

// Send a synchronous request to the server (i.e. sit and wait for the response)
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSLog(@"Reponse from web:%@", response);

// Check if an error occurred    
if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    // Do something to handle/advise user.

    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login error"
                                                      message:@""
                                                     delegate:nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [message show];

}

else {

    // Convert the response data to a string.
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // View the data returned - should be ready for parsing.
    NSLog(@"%@", responseString);

    // Add data to a Plist file for next time
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"login.plist"];

    NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:emailstring,passstring,@"IDtest",nil];
    [values writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    [values release];


    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

This code work fine just for a GET request. I saw it is there a lot of framework (e.g RestKit, ....). But I am getting a bit lost with other request ! So what is the best solution to make POST DELETE PUT request for an IOS App ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's similar code, but using the class NSMutableRequest. You can set the httpbody and other parameters to communicate with the server.

check the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html

to post something, just put setHTTPMethod:@"POST"and assign the data to post using setHTTPBody: